# How to use Django with existing database?

Tags: python, mysql, django, web

I want to create the admin for some tables of an existing MySQL dabatase. I want to use Django since it is just one line of code - admin.site.register(TableName) - so I save a lot of time coding the admin from scratch. I looked here for the inspectdb option of Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/legacy-databases/ but only in the development version https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/ says something about managing the inspected model. I want to know if it is possible and if somebody tried to work with an existing database before but not for read only, I want to manage and edit these database from my Django application.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the development version, don't read the docs for that version. All they say is that - new in that version only - models created via inspectdb will by default be marked as `managed = False`, which means that they can't be modified. But the docs go on to describe exactly how you can modify them, simply by changing that setting.

But of course, you should be using the latest stable version, 1.5, which doesn't do that anyway. You can add and edit items in models from a legacy db to your heart's content.

Comment: I am using the stable version 1.5. So what is the answer? is it possible? have you worked with that before? or you don't know about it? I didn't get your answer you just commented what I wrote about the dev version.

Comment: ... apart from the bit where I say that in the latest stable version you can add and edit items to your heart's content.

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean by "to your heart's content"?